# Python print flexible amount of lists side by side vertically

Tags: python, list

I'm new to python and trying to print a few lists side by side vertically
e.g. `list_1 = [1,2,3]` and `list_2 = [4,5]`:

Output:

```
1 4  
2 5  
3 None
```

I found that `map(None, list_1, list_2)` can achieve this.

However, I may have up to >10 lists to print vertically. I wonder if there is some neat way to do this.

Comment: [`izip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) may be useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `map(None, list_1, list_2, list_3, ...)`, since `map` can take an arbitrary number of arguments.

However, it is usually not a good idea to have numbered variable names. It is often a sign that you should be using a `list` or `tuple` instead. So instead of having variables `list_1`, ..., `list_10`, you should have one variable `columns` which is a list of lists.

If `columns = [list_1, list_2]`, then

```
import itertools as IT
rows = IT.izip_longest(*columns)
```

is equivalent to `map(None, list_1, list_2)` and is compatible with Python3, which removes the `map(None, ...)` option. Notice that this notation generalizes well to arbitrary number of lists without requiring you to type all those variable names by hand.

The `*` in `IT.izip_longest(*columns, ...)` is [Python's unpacking operator](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python/). It unpacks the items in `columns` and sends those items to `IT.izip` as individual arguments. This notation allows you to send an arbitrary number of arguments to a function.